# error adobe flashplayer or html5 browser with webgl or css3d support required in a react native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-4.4-kitkat, react-native-webview, krpano

I have a react native app and i wanted to display a virtual tour made in krpano using React native webview .

I successfully did it in an android 8 device but when i install the app in an android 4.4.4 device it appeared a error message when i enter the virtual part:
error adobe flashplayer or html5 browser with webgl or css3d support required

I tried to install adobe flash player apk but unfortunately it has closed up in 2020.
i even tried to install old versions of React native webview but nothing seemed to work.

How can i make the virtual tour work?